# How to store values of a multiple select in a field as a string of characters in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'diagnostic.store']) !!} 
this is my sight:

<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" name="diagnóstico_rela" id="person3">
  <option selected="selected">orange</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option selected="selected">purple</option>
</select>
<script>


$("#person3").select2({

    tags: true,


})


</script>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

this is my controller:

```
$diagnosticRear_segment = new Rear_segment;
$diagnosticRear_segment->conducta = $request->conducta;
$diagnosticRear_segment->principal_diagnostic_id = $request->principal_diagnostic_id;
$diagnosticRear_segment->diagnóstico_rela = $request->diagnóstico_rela;
$diagnosticRear_segment->ultimo_ontrol = $request->ultimo_ontrol;
$diagnosticRear_segment->próximo_control = $request->próximo_control;
$diagnosticRear_segment->save();
```

I am new in this I thank you for the help provided
in the controller I show all the fields that I keep in that table in the single that in the view I am showing the field that causes me the problem

Comment: You can define array in select box name, so it will post array values to controller. In controller we can implode that posted array valued to make a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your blade file, add an array sign `[]` to the attribute `name` of the `select` tag.

```
<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" name="diagnóstico_rela[]" id="person3">
  <option selected="selected">orange</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option selected="selected">purple</option>
</select>
```

In your controller, `$request->diagnóstico_rela` will return an array of all the selected items.
You can then use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to convert it to a string like this:

```
$diagnosticRear_segment->diagnóstico_rela = implode(', ', $request->diagnóstico_rela);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly .. !! but if I wanted to use it not to save it as a string in a field but to save it as a foreign key in a table, I explained if the diagnostic_field was a foreign key to save several ids in that field as I could do it? I really appreciate your help